# Update element in JSONObject

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, arrays

To avoid bloating up my code checking for NullPointerExceptions at every chance for almost hundred fields, I'd like to replace all "null" references in the object by "0". However, the following code doesn't do it at all.

```
private JSONObject vinfo;
Iterator iter = vinfo.keys();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    String key = (String)iter.next();
    String value = vinfo.getString(key);
    if (value==null){
       vinfo.put(key, "0");
    }
}
```

Any idea how to code that correctly??

Comment: Please can you be more specific about "code doesn't work at all."? Does it change anything? I'm not very familiar with C# but generally I'd start with pushing around `print`s to see what code was even executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.replaceAll()` to your JSON String to replace all the null value to 0.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because your `JSONObject` cannot contain "normal" `null` values, since you cannot put them into it, as Javadoc for `JSONObject.put(String name, Object value)` method says:

> If the value is null, any existing mapping for name is removed.

So the "value" String at line `String value = vinfo.getString(key)` will never be `null`. You should check against `JSONObject.NULL` instead:

```
String key = (String)iter.next();
if (vinfo.isNull(key)) {
    vinfo.put(key, "0");
}
```

Besides, I'm not sure if this line: `vinfo.put(key, "0");` won't give you [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Comment: thanks, a.ch.!

Just for the records and to possibly help others, JSONObject.NULL didn't do it, but "if (value == "null")" did ;-)

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake. You actually should use `JSONObject.isNull(name)` - see the answer edited.